# Do insomniacs yawn?

Tags: neuroscience, physiology, behaviour, neurodegenerative-disorders

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yawn), the jury is still out on the *function* a yawn serves. The article referenced above however writes to say

> Yawning most often occurs in adults immediately before and after sleep, during tedious activities and as a result of its infectious quality. It is commonly associated with tiredness, stress, overwork, lack of stimulation and boredom, though studies show it may be linked to the cooling of the brain

The first sentence there draws my attention. Given a yawn is almost definitely associated with sleep - being expected to occur immediately before, and after.

Does it follow that an insomniac does not yawn?

As a corollary, are there any **known medical conditions** which preclude the act of yawning? For instance, a comatose person *probably* does not yawn.

Comment: Anecdotally, YES insomniacs yawn. Especially when tired from not sleeping

Answer (score 6):

Of course. As you quoted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yawn):

> It is commonly associated with **tiredness, stress**, overwork, lack of stimulation and boredom.

Insomniacs, because they can't get a good sleep, are more tired and stressed than the others.